# how to get account type when login spotify with android sdk

Tags: android, authentication, sdk, spotify, account

I want to use spotify SDK in my app.

When I login in with my premium account in my demo application, play is okay.

If i login in with a free account, play will fail.

I want to check type of account before playing a music.

I mean without try to play music and get error from callback function, just get information from login return message.

Can you tell me how to do it?  Is this supported by now?

I am using android SDK:SpotifySdkAndroid-1.0.0-beta12.

Please help me about this question?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly get the account/product type from the SDK. Instead you need to use the end point "**/v1/me**" or "**/v1/users/{user_id}**". From the JSON data you get in the response get the value of the product which can tell you if its premium or free product.

Refer the below link for more info.

[Web API User Profile Endpoints](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-profile-endpoints/)